# Which rooms can fit 4 people?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Some ships have rooms size 4, but you are only allowed to place 3 people in.

What's going on? Any ideas?

Comment: Fit four people for what?  At most, each room has a single console for use, and the only room with a localized benefit is the medbay.

Comment: @fbueckert: repairing systems, fighting fires, repelling boarders—and on my ship— *breathing*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The medical bay occupies a "2x2" slot, but can always only take 3 people.  It is the only system that "occupies" part of the room.  Every other "large" system (like Engines and Weapons) can hold 4 occupants.  Naturally empty 2x2 rooms can hold occupants as well.

Comment: Thanks. What about medbays on enemy ships (eg. rebel flagship)?

Comment: @ColonelPanic The Rebel Flagship *might* be an exception but I can't recall.  The Rebel Flagship breaks a number of rules (it has unique equipment, powers, and mechanics), so I wouldn't entirely rule it out.  All other Enemy Ships obey standard Medbay mechanics if memory serves.

Comment: The medbay on the flagship can indeed hold 4 people.  Every other medbay that I can recall on an enemy ship actually only holds 2 people.